# How to perform aggregate query in mongooose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I have the following data,

```
[ { type: 'sale' , amount: 2000 }, { type: 'expenditure' , amount: 1300 }, { type: 'sale' , amount: 4090 }, { type: 'expenditure' , amount: 3000 }]
```

The output expected,

```
[ { type: 'sale' , amount: 6090 }, { type: 'expenditure' , amount: 4300 }]
```

I mean I want to perform the summation of 2 types 'sale' and 'expenditure' and I tried as bellow,

```
`
```

```
store.aggregate(
    [
      {
        $group: {
          type: "sale",
          total: {
            $sum: "amount"
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    function(err, result) {
      if (err) {
        res.send(err);
      } else {
        res.json(result);
      }
    }
  );
});
```

`

```
store.aggregate(
    [
      {
        $group: {
          type: "sale",
          total: {
            $sum: "amount"
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    function(err, result) {
      if (err) {
        res.send(err);
      } else {
        res.json(result);
      }
    }
  );
});
```

`

```
  [ { type: 'sale' , amount: 2000 }, { type: 'expenditure' , amount: 1300 }, { type: 'sale' , amount: 4090 }, { type: 'expenditure' , amount: 3000 }]

The output expected,

    [ { type: 'sale' , amount: 6090 }, { type: 'expenditure' , amount: 4300 }]

I mean I want to perform the summation of 2 types 'sale' and 'expenditure' and I tried as bellow,
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write group like this

```
$group: {
    _id: "$type",
    type: "$type",
    amount: {
        $sum: "$amount"
    }
}
```